# How to write a Drush script to retrieve data?

Tags: drush

I want to retrieve a field value by given nodes. Node has a field 'promo code'.

How can I retrieve `imageurl` value by giving 'promo code' field using a drush script?

What is the better way to do it?

I want to get data as a JSON or XML format for all the given nodes.

Comment: Don't have time to answer this right now, but I will give two pointers:  1) start with [drushify](https://www.drupal.org/project/drushify)  2) 'return' rather than 'print' the data; that way, you can use --format=json or --format=xml, and you won't need to write custom formatting code yourself.

Comment: you got some advance?

Answer (score 2):

You can start checking the code of the [Drush Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_entity) module.

> With drush entity you can query the entity system available for Drupal
>   8, 7 and (some of) 6.

And as [Greg](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/131708/how-to-write-drush-script-for-retrive-data#comment165873_131708) says you can use the [Drushify](https://www.drupal.org/project/drushify) module to start.

In this links you can find good references:

- [How to Create Your Own Drush Command](https://www.sitepoint.com/drupal-create-drush-command/)
- [How to write drush commands and hooks](https://www.mikestiv.com/blog/drush-commands-and-hooks)
- [Drush Integration for your modules](http://codekarate.com/content/drush-integration-your-modules)

Comment: Not sure why someone would use Drush for this, unless there is some special use case, but good to know this method exists.

Comment: @NoSssweat I don't have idea, but at least is possible ;-)